# Delete lines from text file - python

Tags: python

I have a text file named `test.txt` that contains:

```
1.  DOC2454556
2.  PEO123PEO123PEO123PEO123
3.  PEO123PEO14PEO123P45O124
4.  PEO123PEO153PEO16PEO1563
5.  SIRFORHE
6.  DOCHELLO
7.  PEO123PEO123PEO123PEO123
8.  PEO123PEO123PEO123PEO123
9.  PEO123PEO123PEO123PEO123
10. SIRFORHE
11. DOC29993
12. PEO193PEO123PEO323PEO123
13. PEO623PEO14PEO142P45O124
14. PEO153PEO143PEO16PEO1563
15. SIRFORHE
```

Here is my code:

```
f= open("C:/Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/test.txt", "r");
print (f.read())
f.close()
```

That gives me an output of:

```
1.  DOC2454556
2.  PEO123PEO123PEO123PEO123
3.  PEO123PEO14PEO123P45O124
4.  PEO123PEO153PEO16PEO1563
5.  SIRFORHE
6.  DOCHELLO
7.  PEO123PEO123PEO123PEO123
8.  PEO123PEO123PEO123PEO123
9.  PEO123PEO123PEO123PEO123
10. SIRFORHE
11. DOC29993
12. PEO193PEO123PEO323PEO123
13. PEO623PEO14PEO142P45O124
14. PEO153PEO143PEO16PEO1563
15. SIRFORHE
```

I would like to make a process that only gives me output like below and then deletes the rest:

```
6.  DOCHELLO
7.  PEO123PEO123PEO123PEO123
8.  PEO123PEO123PEO123PEO123
9.  PEO123PEO123PEO123PEO123
10. SIRFORHE
```

It should only keep lines between DOCHELLO and the first SIRFORHE after the DOCHELLO, so that means 6 through 10.
Basically it will keep a specific range of lines and deletes everything else.

Comment: Reminder if any of these answers helped you, up vote and pick and an answer.

Comment: @Crispy The asker barely put in the effort to write any code themselves, what makes you think they are going to accept an answer?

Comment: I took his rep as an indicator of his time on stack. I assumed he was new, and I was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is assuredly overkill for your simple line selection problem, but it illustrates a nice property of Python: Often a very generalized pattern of behavior or processing can be very generally stated in a way that goes well beyond the original use case. And instead of creating a one-time tool, you can create very flexible, highly reusable meta-tools.

So without further ado, a generator for returning only the lines of a file bounded by two terminal strings, and with a generalized preprocessing facility:

```
import os

def bounded_lines(filepath, start=None, stop=None,
                  preprocess = lambda l: l[:-1]):
    """
    Generator that returns lines from a given file.
    If start is specifed, emits no lines until the
    start line is seen. If stop is specified, stops
    emitting lines after the stop line is seen.
    (The start and stop lines are themselves emitted.)
    Each line can be pre-processed before comparison
    or yielding. By default, this is just to strip the
    final character (the newline or \n) off. But you
    can specify arbitrary transformations, such as
    stripping spaces off the string, folding its case,
    or just whatever.
    """
    preprocess = lambda x: x if preprocess is None else preprocess
    filepath = os.path.expanduser(filepath)
    with open(filepath) as f:
        # find start indicator, yield it
        for rawline in f:
            line = preprocess(rawline)
            if line == start:
                yield line
                break
        # yield lines until stop indicator found, yield
        # it and stop
        for rawline in f:
            line = preprocess(rawline)
            yield line
            if line == stop:
                raise StopIteration


for l in bounded_lines('test.txt', 'DOCHELLO', 'SIRFORHE'):
    print l
```

Comment: If you like this generator approach, see also the `itertools` module, especially its `takewhile` and `dropwhile` functions.

Comment: Will check these out.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will serve your purpose

```
flines = open("test.txt").readlines()                                             
printLine = 0                                                                     
for line in flines:                                                               
   line = line.strip('\n')                                                        
   if 'DOCHELLO' in line:                                                         
      printLine = 1                                                               
   elif 'SIRFORHE' in line:
      if printLine == 1:                                                 
          print line                                                                  
          printLine = 0                                                               
   if printLine == 1:                                                             
       print line
```

Answer (score 0):

## CODE NOT TESTED

Use a boolean to control line captures. Simply set the boolean to true when `DOCHELLO` appears, then every line until `SIRFORHE` would be appended to our list of wanted lines.

When `SIRFORHE` appears we add the list to a dictionary then clear the list.
This way you know what sequence the lines were recorded in.

```
# Open the file
f = open("C:/Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/result.txt", "r")
flines = f.readlines()

# Create some variables
start = False
start_counter = 0
data_seq = {}     # data sequ
lines = []

# Record wanted lines
for line in flines:
    if 'DOCHELLO' == line :
        start_counter += 1
        start = True
    elif 'SIRFORHE' == line :
        data_seq[start_counter] = lines
        lines =[] # Reset lines
        start = False

    if start: lines += [line]

# Output the recorded lines
for i, lines in data_seq.items():
    print
    print 'On the %d occurrence of capturing' % i
    print lines
    print
```

Comment: I'm sure you can tinker with this and reduce the variables and lines needed to achieve the same results

Answer (score -1):

This is by no means the most efficient way to go about it, but it works in a fix.

```
start = 6
end = 10
output= open("C:/Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/result.txt", "w")
lineCounter = 0
for line in f:
    if(lineCounter >= start):
       output.write(line)
       if(line == end):
           break
    lineCounter += 1
f.close()
output.close()
```